# A question about "be"

Tags: grammar, be

A short question today about the usage of "be" without using "to" in front of it.

Here is an example of each situation:
1. "He requested that the new car be fast."
2. "He requested for the new car to be fast."

Are these both correct, or is example 1 a bit funny?

Comment: Actually, "requesting for" something is perfectly correct in the phrasing that @Luca is using.  "Resquested for" is just another way of saying "asked for."

Comment: Example 1 sounds good to me. Example 2 is the funny-sounding one, because of "requested for" (as @WillBriggs said, but he meant Example 2, not Example 1); it should be "asked for" if you really want to use "for".

Answer (score 0):

The second phrase using the prepositions *for* and *to* is less clear. I simplify sentences using the [paramedic method](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/635/01/).